# Xamarin lowering video size

Tags: ios, video, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i want to "compress" videos (for upload) in Xamarin (iOS).
I found out about the AVAssetWriter Class and i red that you could set the resolution, bitrate etc. 
How would you use it? Which other classes?
As you may already noticed, im very new to app development.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample using AVAssetReader to feed AVAssetWriter to **re-sample** and/or **transcode** a video.

In this example, I am taking a video named "Pool.mp4" that was included in app bundle (BundleResource) and saving into the "tmp" directory as "NewVideo.mp4" at a size of 300x300 at 1Mbps (reducing the original file size by ~50%...)

**Note**: No return values or error codes are being checked, that is left up to the implementor.

```
var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename("Pool.mp4"));
NSError assetReaderError;
var assetReader = AVAssetReader.FromAsset(asset, out assetReaderError);
var assetTrack = asset.Tracks.First();
var inputSettings = new AVVideoSettingsUncompressed() 
{
    Height = 300,
    Width = 300,
};
var assetReaderOutput = new AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(assetTrack, settings: inputSettings);
assetReaderOutput.AlwaysCopiesSampleData = false;

string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "NewVideo.mp4");
if (File.Exists(tempFile)) File.Delete(tempFile);
var url = NSUrl.FromFilename(tempFile);
NSError assetWriterError;
var assetWriter = new AVAssetWriter(url, AVFileType.Mpeg4, out assetWriterError);
var outputSettings = new AVVideoSettingsCompressed()
{
    Height = 300,
    Width = 300,
    Codec = AVVideoCodec.H264,
    CodecSettings = new AVVideoCodecSettings
    {
        AverageBitRate = 1000000
    }
};
var assetWriterInput = new AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.Video, outputSettings: outputSettings);
assetWriterInput.ExpectsMediaDataInRealTime = false;
assetWriter.AddInput(assetWriterInput);

assetWriter.StartWriting();
assetReader.AddOutput(assetReaderOutput);
assetReader.StartReading();
assetWriter.StartSessionAtSourceTime(CoreMedia.CMTime.Zero);

var mediaInputQueue = new DispatchQueue("mediaInputQueue");
assetWriterInput.RequestMediaData(mediaInputQueue, () =>
{
    while (assetWriterInput.ReadyForMoreMediaData)
    {
        var nextBuffer = assetReaderOutput.CopyNextSampleBuffer();
        if (nextBuffer != null)
        {
            assetWriterInput.AppendSampleBuffer(nextBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            assetWriterInput.MarkAsFinished();
            assetWriter.FinishWritingAsync();
            assetReader.CancelReading();
            assetReader.Dispose();
            assetReaderOutput.Dispose();
            assetWriter.Dispose();
            assetWriterInput.Dispose();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it out!